# Convert CLOB to Base64 Binary C#

Tags: c#, oracle, web-services, base64, clob

I have a CLOB field which is reading from Oracle to C#, I need to read this CLOB and want to convert to Base64 Binary for submitting to a WebService.

I am new to C#.

I went through some threads but was unable to find a solution.

Anybody else done this before?

Comment: What is the encoded content of the clob? A unicode string?

Comment: Dear Alex, the content is big XML file.